# superslow swipe reaction - how to speed up sencha touch / phonegap

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, performance

i have a simple sencha touch app in mvc style with one view in the viewport: the main view.  another panel is popping up as modal floating window when you swipe a finger over the main view. this panel lies inside a variable of the main view script. 
my problem: on iOs devices (via phonegap) the popup appears really late - like 2-4 seconds after the swipe happend.
is this normal or are there ways to speed up sencha touch/phonegap, maybe by preloading the popup, preopening it and making it innvisible...?

thnx!

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but you may want to look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307732/why-does-javascript-run-so-slow-on-iphone the iphone doesn't do jit compiling on javascript through webview (only in safari).  So sencha touch is faster in safari on iOS than phonegap (webview).  Just a heads up while you research this.

Comment: I'm fairly certain this has changed since iOS 5.0 where the nitro engine was given to webviews. No longer just safari for nitro javascript engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you aren't installing your app in debug when testing on your device, it's painfully slow.

Comment: When you install the app on your device locally to test it is a choice in the Run/Debug options.  If you're in debug mode there will be a check by it.

Comment: Did this fix your issue? I ask because I am in the process of evaluating the use of Sencha Touch + Phonegap for developing a cross platform mobile application and I am interested in performance issues.

Comment: In my case it didn't work :(, as far as the quality of the answer I think that this answer is split into 2 parts, it would be better if the comment from May 10 was edited as part of the answer.